# JQuery UI 1.10.2 - How to get resize handles visible inside dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

The resize handles don't show on dialog or in anything I try to resizablify inside a dialog. I know [this is by design](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4575) that they are disabled in the themes, but how do I get them visible? I need to see them in the dialog content and the ones for the dialog would not hurt either.

```
<p><a href="#dialog">Dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
  <p>foobar</p>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid;" id="bar">BAR</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('a[href=#dialog]').click( function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault(); 
          $('#dialog').dialog({
              open: function() {
                   $('#bar').resizable({handles:'sw,se,e'});   
              }
          });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Also in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s22nx/

Comment: Have you tried $("#dialog").dialog("option", "resizable", true);

Comment: Have you seen my answer yet?

Comment: @andyb Yes, I have. Sorry for not being able to test it - I'm super busy at the moment! I will test it and accept as soon as I get a few hours of free time to play with this thing. I can't test this at home; this is for a work project :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here contributing to the problem, one of them *could* be a bug.

Firstly, you are correct that the *south-east* handle was hidden intentionally, however all [8 handles](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) still exist as elements in the dialog. This is good news since you can add the following CSS to bring the `se` handle back. It's a bit of a hack to get around the intentional hiding and you might want to adjust the `right` and `bottom` positioning to suit your needs.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    right:0 !important;
    bottom:0 !important;
    background-position: -64px -224px !important;
}
```

The other grabbers seem to by design have no style associated with them. None of the [themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) I checked have any *visible* style (aside from the `cursor`). Search for `.ui-resizable-` in the [jquery-ui.css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css) to see this.

This is sort of covered in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) but only mentioned in the context of generating your own handles. There is nothing explicit about existing theme support. Luckily all the handles share a class, so we can make them all visible by adding:

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Or just one side, for example:

```
.ui-resizable-s {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

The possible bug I mentioned was to do with controlling the generation of handle elements. The code in question `$('#bar').resizable({handles:'sw,se,e'});` should be correct and result in only 3 handle elements but all 8 always appear.

In the `_makeResizable` function in [`jquery-ui.js`](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js) (v1.10.2) the line:

```
resizeHandles = typeof handles === "string" ? handles : "n,e,s,w,se,sw,ne,nw";
```

should set the correct resizeHandles to the value you supply as an options parameter but `typeof handles = 'object'` for me, so jQueryUI is using the else part of the ternary.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this is the way to go. I eventually decided not to use resizable at all, it just confused my users.

Answer (score 3):

In the css file, I had to change:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}
```

to:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you just forget to include required css

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Check [this](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)

**UPD**
[They do get handles, they're just not visible with the default theme. This isn't something specific to jQuery UI. Many resizable windows work this way.](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9217#comment:3)